# How do I return the value of a redirected link in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, puppeteer

**Goal:** I am trying to finish the first step in the authentication process for a website (api). To do so, the last step is to obtain a code that is in the url (address bar) once it has redirected (this is my guess).

In short, I have figured out how to input the username / password. From there it loads a new page, and then that page loads another page (my best guess is that it checks to ensure all the information is correct) which holds a code in the url.

```js
var puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
let clientInfo = require("./Client_Information.json");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    `https://url-goes-here.com?response_type=code&client_id=${clientInfo.client_id}`
  );
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./ScreenShots/ScreenShot.png" });
  // Enter username GOOD
  await page.click("#user_id");
  await page.keyboard.type(clientInfo.user_name);
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./ScreenShots/ScreenShot1.png" });
  console.log("Username has been inserted");
  // Accepting Username GOOD
  await page.click(".andes-button--large");
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./ScreenShots/ScreenShot2.png" });
  await page.keyboard.press("Accept"); //Enter Key
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./ScreenShots/ScreenShot3.png" });
  //Delay 1.5 Seconds
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  // Enter Password GOOD
  await page.click("#password");
  await page.keyboard.type(clientInfo.password);
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./ScreenShots/ScreenShot4.png" });
  console.log("Password has been inserted");
  // Accepting Password GOOD
  await page.click("#action-complete");
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./ScreenShots/ScreenShot5.png" });
  await page.keyboard.press("Accept"); //Enter Key
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./ScreenShots/ScreenShot6.png" });
  //Delay 4 Seconds
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  //URL Fetch GOOD
  const url1 = await page.url();
  console.log("Page URL : " + url1);
  //Store URL
  clientInfo.Step1_Url = url1;
  //NOTE New Section
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
  const url2 = await page.url();
  console.log("Page URL : " + url2);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

In the //NOTE New Section area is where I am waiting to get the actual resolve redirect, though instead I get **chrome-error://chromewebdata/** vs the expected url+code. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you run the script with `headless: false`? What's going on in there? Have you debugged the script? What other observations did you make out of it?

Comment: I am very green when it comes to this, I am not sure how to debug the script, though I can google how to run with headless false.

Comment: after running in headless, I still have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

the Issue was with the redirect_uri. I had it set to localhost and that seemingly was causing puppeteer to not be able to retrieve it. Upon changing this to heroku, it worked instantly.